# Regex - How to create a regex to check two strings with different length but one depends on the other

Tags: regex

If there is a string like this "abcdefghijklm.com 80 /abcdefgh.php" where the domainname followed by http port and the sub string is  first 8 digits of the domain name always and followed by ".php"  (the sub-string character will change to 6 OR 8 OR 5 at times but however all those length would contain same characters of domain name and endswith .php
     more examples like this,

```
xyzklmopqr.com 80 xyzklm.php  
lkjhgfdsaq.com 80 lkjhg.php  
mjuyhnbgtr.com 80 mjuyhnbg.php
```

Comment: 1) show your own attempts. 2) use your real account,  it's ok to ask a freakin question.

Answer (score 2):

This works and you can easily change the numbers

```
(\w{5,6}|\w{8})\w*\.com 80 \1\.php
```

It's a little simpler than the other guy's solution

Comment: +1, I think this is a little less efficient then my version since there will be more need for backtracking, but it is definitely easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
(((\w{5})\w?)\w{2}?)\w*\.com 80 (\1|\2|\3)\.php
```

Note that this works for the specific lengths you mentioned in your question (5, 6, and 8), not for any generic length substring.

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/NwCcihN6o6

Answer (score 0):

I would try `([a-z]{6})\S* 80 \1\.php`

That would work for your 6 case, you can change the number as needed for your other cases.